# In Github action, I can not pass string argument to reusable workflow

Tags: input, arguments, github-actions, workflow

reusable-workflow.yml

```
name: Print destination
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      destination:
        type: string
        required: true
jobs:
  print_destination:
    runs-on: [ self-hosted ]
    steps:
      - name: Print inputs
        run: |
          echo "destination:" ${{ github.event.inputs.destination }}
```

trigger.yml

```
name: Pass destination
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  print_destination:
    uses: myaccount/myrepository/.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml@main
    with:
      destination: myword
```

result:

```
Run echo "destination:" 
  echo "destination:" 
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
destination:
```

Current runner version: '2.293.1'

I expect that the result prints `myword` but it does not. Can somebody tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Use `inputs.destination` instead of `github.event.inputs.destination`. See [example](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-of-onworkflow_callinputs).

Comment: @Azeem Thank you. I got the essence. Actually, I'd like to use `workflow_dispatch` and `workflow_call` in `reusable-workflow.yml`, so I need some `IF` block to determine between `inputs.destination` and `github.event.inputs.destination`. Is there any example?

Comment: But, you only have `workflow_call` in your reusable workflow. Why do you want to check for other events?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71458189/github-action-workflow-call-does-not-use-up-to-date-input-values